# Не копируется/записывается файл в директорию приложения.NPException

Tags: java, android, файловая-система

Использую apache.io.

```
    //создаю папку для картинки.
File dir= new File(getFilesDir()+"/my_img_for_icon");
     dir.mkdir();

    //Задаю путь и имя для картинки. 
File image = new File(getFilesDir()+"/my_img_for_icon/img_user.jpg");
    //Копирую картинку , полученную по uri(imageFile)..
    //imageFile не пустой,но получаю NullPointerException..  
FileUtils.copyFile(imageFile,image);
```

Во многих аппаратах работает,не работает на android 6.0 Marshmallow.

Comment: вы ложите стектрейс, где эта ошибка